# XML data to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I have the following XML. The child nodes and the individual values of the childnodes would form a json structure which is provided below formatted

```
 <classification>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <Age>Child</Age>
    <SkinTone>Medium</SkinTone>
    <HeightType>Average,Tall</HeightType>
    <Build></Build>
    <HairColor></HairColor>
    <HairLength></HairLength>
    <ClothesFullBodyType></ClothesFullBodyType>
    <ClothesFullBodyColor></ClothesFullBodyColor>
    <ClothesFullBodyPattern></ClothesFullBodyPattern>
    <ClothesUpperBodyType></ClothesUpperBodyType>
    <ClothesUpperBodyColor></ClothesUpperBodyColor>
    <ClothesUpperBodyPattern></ClothesUpperBodyPattern>
    <ClothesLowerBodyType></ClothesLowerBodyType>
    <ClothesLowerBodyColor></ClothesLowerBodyColor>
    <ClothesLowerBodyPattern></ClothesLowerBodyPattern>
    <FootwearType></FootwearType>
    <FootwearColor></FootwearColor>
    <Headwear></Headwear>
    <Glasses></Glasses>
    <FacialHair></FacialHair>
    <Carrying></Carrying>
</classification>
```

I wish to have output in json format like

```
  [
   {
     "keyname":"gender",
     "keyvalue:"Male" 
   },
   {
     "keyname":"age",
     "keyvalue:"child" 
   },
   {
     "keyname":"skintone",
     "keyvalue:"Medium" 
   },
   {
     "keyname":"heighttype",
     "keyvalue:"Average,Tall" 
   },       {
     "keyname":"build",
     "keyvalue:" " 
   },
   ........
   ........
]
```

Below is my code which I tried. I get all "keyvalue" for everyfields

```
    var all = $(MYXMLobj).children("classification")[0].getElementsByTagName("*");
    var classificationArray = [];
    for(var pp=0; pp<all.length; pp++){
        classificationArray.push({"keyname":all[pp],"keyvalue":$(MYXMLobj).children("classification").children(all[pp]).text()});
    }
```

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what OS are you on?

Comment: linux fedora...

Comment: are you able to install some command-line tools?

Comment: If you use Node.js, use the correct tag. Or tag it at least with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I shortened xml string to avoid bulky code. Here is what I got with pure JS:

```js
let toParse = `
<classification>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <Age>Child</Age>
    <SkinTone>Medium</SkinTone>
    <HeightType>Average,Tall</HeightType>
    <Build></Build>
    <HairColor></HairColor>
</classification>`;

let xmlObj = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(toParse, "text/xml");
let all = xmlObj.children[0].children;
let classificationArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  classificationArray.push({
    "keyname": all[i].tagName,
    "keyvalue": all[i].innerHTML
  });
}

console.log(classificationArray);
```

So why your code doesn't work properly?

That's because of `$(MYXMLobj).children("classification").children(all[pp]).text()`. The `all[pp]` is an object `Element` (e.g. `<Gender>Male</Gender>`), not a string as you may want(e.g. `"Gender"`). So `.children(all[pp])` returns all children and then `.text()` is being aplied to every child. And in the result you have `"MaleChildMediumAverage,Tall"` (in my shortened xml).